# When using monaco-editor in vite ,An error was rejected,

Tags: vuejs3, vite, monaco-editor

```
nextTick(() => {
    // init
    const node = document.getElementById('monacoElement');
    if (node) {
        monacoEditor.value = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(node, {
        theme: 'vs', 
        roundedSelection: false, 
        autoIndent: true, 
        readOnly: false,
        language: 'json',
    })
    const oldValModel = monaco.editor.createModel(props.oldVal, "json")
    const newValModel = monaco.editor.createModel(props.newVal, "json")
    monacoEditor.value.setModel({
    original: oldValModel,
    modified: newValModel
    })
    }
})
```

[image]

when I use monaco.editor.create(),it runs normal,but when I use monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(), in runs fail

I tried to add vite-plugin-monaco-editor but it doesnot work .A same error was rejecetd.Another,I tried to add an attribute named getWorker on window ,the same result